# Spark dataframe concat multiple columns into one with optional columns in some row using Java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe. I want to concat multiple columns into one, with some rows not having some of the mentioned columns in concat

```
id  mid colA colB
1   1    X     T
2   1    R
3   2          P
```

If i use

```
df.withColumn("colC", functions.concat("colA","colB")).drop("colA").drop("colB")
```

it only returns

```
id  mid  colC
1   1     X
1   1     T
2   1     null
3   2     null
```

as second and third row of the input does not have value for both colA and colB

Comment: how about first replacing the Empty feilds with `""` ?

Comment: Your output doesn't match with the code that you have used. Are you using any other operation as well that you might have missed adding here?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.na.fill("", Seq("colA", "colB"))
 .withColumn("colC", concat(col("colA"), col("colB")))
```